# Ajax request don't pass the files of the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have the problem that form don't pass one variable.

My table:

```
Schema::create('projects', function(Blueprint $table)

    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->integer('order');
        $table->integer('public')->default(1);
        $table->string('pathheader')->default('/');
        $table->string('pathhome')->default('/');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have this blade, with some forms(i will put the ajax after this code)

```
@extends('cms.public.layouts.default')
@section('content')
<div class="col-md-10">
    <h3 style="letter-spacing:40px;text-align:center;color:f15d5e;">PROYECTOS</h3>
</div>

<div id="listall"> <!-- DIV TO LIST ALL THE PROJECTS START HERE -->
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:20px;">
          <button type="button" id="buttoncreate" class="btn btn-danger">Crear Proyecto</button>

        </div>
                      <table class="table">
                  <thead style="color:white">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Slug</th>
                      <th>Order</th>
                      <th>Public</th>
                      <th>Fecha creación</th>
                      <th>Fecha ultima actualización</th>
                      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody style="color:white">
                  @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                    <tr>
                      <th>{{$project->id}}</th>
                      <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->created_at))}}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->updated_at))}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                  @endforeach
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
  <br><br>
</div>  <!-- DIV TO LIST ALL THE PROJECTS END HERE -->

<div id="form1" style="display:none;" class="col-md-8"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->
    <div>
    <h3>Crear nuevo proyecto</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="formcreateproject">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.projects.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm" name="myForm">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label name="title">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="order">Order:</label>
            <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="public">Public:</label>
            <input type="number" id="public" name="public" class="form-control form-control-sm">
             <label name="body">Header</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <label name="body">Home</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
            <br><br><br>

          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
</div> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 END HERE-->

<div id="form2" style="display:none;" class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-">
    <h3>Crear nuevo proyecto</h3>
    </div>
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label name="title">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="order">Order:</label>
            <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="public">Public:</label>
            <input type="number" id="public" name="public" class="form-control form-control-sm">
             <label name="body">Header</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <label name="body">Home</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <br><br><br>

          </div>
        </form>
</div>

</div>
@stop
```

And this is the ajax code:

```
//Javascript view /projects/menu.blade.php
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttoncreate").click(function(){
        $("#listall").hide();
        $("#form1").fadeIn(1000);

    });

    $("#createprojectsubmit").click(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit();
    });

    $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
            type:'post',
            data:$('#myForm').serializeArray(),
            success: function(){
                $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When ajax is executed i check the form data and it show me this lines:

```
_token:ymzuWLO6I0nl7z5CQEBNJ4Af51NfriftjP1swWmH
slug:Test3
order:1
public:1
```

It give me an error:

> Call to a member function getRealPath() on null
>
> at FilesystemAdapter->putFileAs('Test3', null, 'header.png')

I put the controller code too:

```
public function storeProject(Request $request)
        {
        $project = new Project();
        $project->slug = $request->input("slug");
        $project->order = $request->input("order");
        $project->public = $request->input("public");
        $project->pathheader = $request->file('pathheader');
        $project->pathhome = $request->file('pathhome');
        \Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
        \Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathheader,'header.png');
        \Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathhome,'home.png');
        $project->save();
        }
```

The problem is on $project->pathhome and $project->pathheader, they're null, know why?

Thanks a lot, if need more information ask it please.

Comment: check your routes once more

Comment: Routes are good, if i do it without ajax it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using `FormData()`:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/projects/postUpload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
            //alert(data);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

The above is a sample code, but you may use it to modify it.

Comment: Hi, i try it and give me this error: `Call to a member function getRealPath() on null
` `at FilesystemAdapter->putFileAs(null, null, 'header.png')`

Answer (score 0):

To sending files using ajax you need to add the following code within your ajax request.

```
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url:'',
```

After adding this code your code look like.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type:'post',
            //data:$('#myForm').serializeArray(),
            success: function(){
                $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Then try with `FormData()`

Answer (score 0):

Add meta on the header so the csrf will be verified

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Comment: I have this on layout :)